# Show if $n \neq m$ then $\int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{im \theta}e^{-in \theta}= 0$

Tags: complex-analysis

The full question is if $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ then $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{im \theta}e^{-in \theta}= \begin{cases}2\pi & \text{ if }n=m\\0 & \text{ if }n\not= m\end{cases}$ . I know how to show when n=m but I'm getting stuck on showing $n \neq m$. I get to where I have $$\int_{0}^{2 \pi} e^{im \theta}e^{-in \theta}=\frac{e^{m-n}-1}{i(m-n)} $$ but I do not know how to show that is equal to 0. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get $e^{m-n}$ from?

Comment: I got $e^{i2 \pi (m-n)} = e^{i 2 \pi }e^{(m-n)}$ and since $e^{i2 \pi} = 1$ that leaves you with $e^{(m-n)}$.

Comment: I'd double check that - you should end up with $1^{m-n}$.

Comment: @mconn7 your calculations there are incorrect. :)

Comment: @avid19 Which part is incorrect? Not sure where I go wrong

Comment: @mconn7 $e^{ab}\neq e^{a}e^{b}$

Comment: @mconn7 In fact $(m-n)$ is just some integer. So $e^{i2\pi(m-n)}=1$

Comment: @avid19 Ah yes and then because (m-n) is an integer $e^{i2 \pi}$ is not really effected by it so you get $1^{(m-n)} = 1$. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :**

$\bullet$  For $m\not= n , $$\displaystyle\text{Integral}=\left[\frac{e^{i(m-n)\theta}}{i(m-n)}\right]_0^{2\pi}=?$

$\bullet$ What is the value of $\displaystyle e^{2k\pi i}$ for $k$ is an integer ?

Comment: Yes i already got that part. I get stuck after that.

Comment: @mconn7) See edit..

Comment: Yes thank you I see I was making the stupid mistake of thinking $e^{ab} = e^ae^b$ which it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
e^{i\theta m}e^{-i\theta n}=e^{i\theta k}
$$
where $k=m-n\in\Bbb Z$; hence $n=m$ iff $k=0$.

Moreover the primitive of $e^{i\theta k}$ is $\frac1{ik}e^{i\theta k}+c$ for $k\neq0$; thus, in this case we have that
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\theta m}e^{-i\theta n}\,d\theta
=\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\theta k}\,d\theta
=\frac1{ik}(e^{i2\pi k}-e^{0})=0
$$
since $e^{i2\pi k}=e^0=1$.

If otherwise $k=0$, $e^{i\theta k}=1$,  hence
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i\theta m}e^{-i\theta n}\,d\theta
=\int_0^{2\pi}1\,d\theta=2\pi\neq0.
$$